# Can an Atom be negatively as well as positively charged simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons, atoms, ions

For example there are three atoms- atom A, atom B, atom C. Atom A has 3 electrons, atom B has 4 electrons and atom C has 2 electrons. If we bring together atom A and atom B, in this case atom A is positively charged in atom B's view. If we bring together atom A and atom C, in this case atom A is negatively charged in atom C's view. So does it mean that an atom can  be negatively as well as positively charged at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An atom can be positively charged as well as negatively charged. The charged form of an atom (or molecule), which has either more or fewer electrons than protons, is called an [ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion).

It cannot be both at the same time, though, and that is because you are viewing positive and negative charge as relative things (*"atom A is negatively charged in atom C's view"*), which charge is not.

Things are neutral when they don't move when exposed to an electric field. They are "negatively charged" when they are repelled by an electron, and they are "positively charged" when they are attracted by an electron, there is nothing relative about this definition.